# When is a gravatar shown for a user with a profile pic?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-picture, gravatar

> [image][image]

Gilles is a fairly well-known user, so imagine my surprise when I see a gravatar icon for his profile pic (or whatever it's called) instead of the customary mushrooms (?!). Yet when I hovered over the pic, the pop-up box showed the proper image. I checked out chat, and there too, the tiny pic which comes up with an `@mention` showed the proper one. What's happening?

Comment: Just came here to report this on my own profile. No end of annoying.

Comment: There are some issues with pictures caching at the moment. SE is aware and working on it.

Comment: and it's just not right not presenting Gilles as a "fun guy"...(sorry, couldn't help it)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the latest build, a bug slipped through on some code that refactored profile image rendering.

A fix is being pushed out right now.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks! That's quick response!